# conda command not found in docker container after commit and push

Tags: python, docker, anaconda, environment-variables

I built a docker container with anaconda and other packages. in the container, I used `echo "export PATH="/root/anaconda3/bin:$PATH""` and `~/.bashrc` and `/bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc""`, conda command worked fine, and the python version was correct.

however, when committed and pushed the container to the docker hub, and then pulled it elsewhere, it gave me "bash: conda: command not found" when i tried to use conda command.

Would anyone tell me how to solve this problem? Any advice or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve].  That should include your image's Dockerfile and the `docker build` and `docker run` commands you used to create and execute it.  You should almost never use `docker commit` since it's all but impossible to reproduce the image later.

Answer (score 0):

Find the result of this problem myself.

I build and commit this docker in one machine with root permission，and the Anaconda3 was installed in /root/anaconda3/bin. I then pulled and run this docker in another machine without root permission, in which the installation path can't be accessed. I thus got the "conda command not found" error.

To solve this problem, it seems that I have to ture to someone with root permission for help. Thank @David Maze anyway.